# Get content-disposition

Tags: angular, api, xlsx

I'm having troubles to get "content-disposition" from my response header, other responses like content-length and content-type I can get. the method in API returns me an xlxs and in the content-disposition is the name of the file.

Here is the call for the API:

```
public getChecklist(idConta: any, idCobranca: any) {
const token = this.token.retornaToken();
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  Accept: 'application/octet-stream',
});

return this.http
  .get(
    `${API}/fill-checklist?idConta=${idConta}&idCobranca=${idCobranca}`,
    { headers, observe:'response', responseType: 'blob' }
  );
}
```

Every thing is running perfect, I just can't get the name of the file.